# Bash: Only one file processed with $1 but all with hard coded value

Tags: bash, file-rename

This bash code working as expected (renaming file) with the hard coded value viz. `~/Music/*.mp3`. But it does not work (just processes only the first file) with `files=($1)` when I pass CLI argument: `./rfs.sh ~/Music/*.mp3`

**`rfs.sh`**

```sh
files=(~/Music/*.mp3)

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do
    oldname="${files[$i]}"
    newname=`echo "$oldname" | sed -E 's/\/[0-9]+ /\//'`
    echo "$oldname ---> $newname"
    mv "$oldname" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: when you pass `~/Music/*.mp3` on the command line it's being expanded into a list of all matching files, eg, if you have 3x mp3 files (1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3) then you're effectively calling your script like such: `./rfs.sh ~/Music/1.mp3 ~/Music/2.mp3 ~/Music/3.mp3`, and since your code says `files=($1)` => you're only processing the first file passed in on the command line; try `files=($@)` or alternatively you could try `./rfs.sh '~/Music/*.mp3'` and then see what `files=($1)` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What markp-fuso said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239542/bash-only-one-file-processed-with-1-but-all-with-hard-coded-value#comment110076141_62239542) is exactly right.

Here is how you do what you're aiming for in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (*remove the `echo` if you like the results*)

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"; do
  dirname=${file%/*}
  basename=${file##*/}

   echo mv "$file ${dirname}/${basename//[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]* /}"
done
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ ls *.mp3
'1234 foo.mp3'  '5678 bar.mp3'

$ mp3(){ for file in "$@"; do dirname=${file%/*}; basename=${file##*/}; echo mv "$file ${dirname}/${basename//[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]* /}"; done;}; mp3 ./*.mp3
mv ./1234 foo.mp3 ./foo.mp3
mv ./5678 bar.mp3 ./bar.mp3
```

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for something in bash :( but passing in arguments, and the above works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s `rename` :

```
rename -n 's!/\d+\s+!/!' ~/Music/*.mp3
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>